# stripe future subscription is not working

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, stripe-connect

I am working on future subscription, when i run the code, It create 2 subscription 1 is active and another is trial, don't know why is it creating 2 subscription ?  For that active subscription it creates payment that is wrong, i have set the `trial_end` as "2018-06-20" still it started subscription from today, can anyone please help me how can i resolve this issue ? here i have added my code

```
<?php
require_once('init.php');
if (isset($_POST['stripeToken'])) {
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("*****************");
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiVersion("2018-05-21");
    $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    try {
        $plan_id = time();
    /************ check if plan exists ***************/
    $plan_created = \Stripe\Plan::create(array(
                "amount" => 1200,
                "interval" => "day",
                "product" => array(
                "name" => "test",
                ),  
                "currency" => "usd",
                "id" => $plan_id,
            )
    );

        //Create Customer:
        $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                    'source' => $token,
            'description'=> 'Test Customer',
                    'email' => 'testabc123@gmail.com',
                    'plan' => $plan_id
        ));
        // Charge the order:
    $dateTime = new DateTime('2018-06-20'); 
    $date_timestamp = $dateTime->format('U');

        $charge = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
                    'customer' => $customer->id,
                    "items" => array(
                        array(
                            "plan" => $plan_id,
                        ),
                    ),
            "trial_end"=>$date_timestamp,
                )
        );

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($charge);
    die;

    } catch (Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
        // The card has been declined
    }
}
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
    <script src="http://checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
            data-key="pk_test_4Ak5l6azsnSsVrpVJbIepoBu"
    data-amount="5000" data-description="One year's subscription"></script>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").trigger("click");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you created `PLANs` on Stripe? If not, then create a plan and then call subscribe method of Stripe library.

Comment: Yes i have created i have added it in my code, can you please check my code

Comment: Have you set Trial period within one plan? If not you should do, so when the trial period gets over, the charge will be taken for the main plan.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing two subscriptions is that your creates two of them. The first is created when you call `Customer::Create` and pass the plan:

`'plan' => $plan_id`

This subscription has no trial period because you didn't specify one on the plan and that is all that is used when creating this particular subscription.

The other, separate subscription was created from your `Subscription::create` call. This is the correct subscription and it has the correct trial period set.

To fix this issue, I would just remove the `plan` from where you create the Customer and keep your existing code for creating the subscription, since that works fine.